# Type 'PersonAddress[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<PersonAddress[]>' in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm having the service response as below

```
    [
  {
   name: 'ravi',
   address: [
     {
      street: 'ABC Colony',
      city: 'Irvine',
      country: 'US',
      zip: '12345-1255'
    }
   ],
   phone: '9123456789'
   }
];
```

I need to bind address which I'm wrote as below <.ts file>

```
export class PersonCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() personAddress: Observable<PersonAddress[]>;

  constructor(private service: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.list(null, null, null)
      .subscribe((res: Person[]) => {
        this.personAddress= res[0].address; **//Error Line**
      });    
  }
}
```

Note: I need to use async pipe for this. and I only need to return/assign address array object at this.personAdddress.

1. Person[] - model class

   export class Person{
     name: string;
     address: PersonAddress[];
     phone: string;
   }
2. PersonAddress[] - model class

   export class PersonAddress{
        street: string;
        city: string;
        country: string;
        zip; string;
   }

Comment: The error you posted and code does not seems to match

Comment: You are doing exactly what the error says, you are assigning an object of type `PersonAddress[]` to a member of type `Observable<PersonAddress[]>`. Use this instead: `this.personAddress = this.service.list(null, null, null).map((res: Person[]) => {
        return res[0].address as PersonAddress[];
      });`. Also, your question's title is wrong, it doesn't match the same error you describe on the body.

Comment: Any alternative for without using array index as 'res[0].address'. Since Person array object always have one item.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question title is totally misguiding, anyhow according to your code you need to assign an array

```
this.personAddress = this.service.list(null, null, null).map((res: Person[]) => { return res[0].address as PersonAddress[]; });
```

Comment: I can't able to edit the question now. it should be as   Type 'PersonAddress[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<PersonAddress[]>' in angular 2

Comment: Any alternative for without using array index as 'res[0].address'. Since Person array object always have one item.